# facing issue to setup nodejs version 18 for azure function via serverless deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy NodeJS code to azure function via serverless framework. It is working correctly for node 14 but facing issue when I tried to deploy is node 18.

Ideally after deployment FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION should set to ~4 but it is set as ~3

I am using below serverless yml file

```
service: node-azure

provider:
  name: azure
  region: East US
  stage: dev
  runtime: nodejs18

plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .gitignore
    - package.json
    - .git/**

functions:
  hello:
     handler: handler.hello
     events:
       - http: true
         x-azure-settings:
           authLevel: anonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating and deploying **Nodejs Function** with **serverless** and yes by default it will take **`nodejs12`** as a **Function runtime** for nodejs template, But **`nodejs14`**, **`nodejs18`**, **`nodejs20`** are also supported parameters:-

> Note- Runtime **version 3** will also work but its going to be deprecated so you can upgrade it to **Version 4**

Refer my [**Github Repository**](https://github.com/sid24desai/Functionserverless1) for the serverless project.

**My Default server.yml with `nodejs18`:-**

```yaml
service: functionserverless1


frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: azure
  region: West US 2
  runtime: nodejs18
  # os: windows  # windows is default, linux is available
  # prefix: "sample"  # prefix of generated resource name
  subscriptionId: 0xxxxxxxx6e97cb2a7
  # type: premium  

  environment: 
    VARIABLE_FOO: 'foo'

 
plugins: # look for additional plugins in the community plugins repo: https://github.com/serverless/plugins
  - serverless-azure-functions

# you can add packaging information here
package:
  patterns:
    # - '!exclude-me.js'
    # - '!exclude-me-dir/**'
    - '!local.settings.json'
    - '!.vscode/**'
    # - include-me.js
    # - include-me-dir/**

functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.sayHello
    events:
      - http: true
        methods:
          - GET
        authLevel: anonymous 

  goodbye:
    handler: src/handlers/goodbye.sayGoodbye
    events:
      - http: true
        methods:
          - GET
        authLevel: anonymous
```

***Commands:-***

Refer [**here**](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/quick-start) for more details.

```bash
npm i -g serverless
sls create -t azure-nodejs -p FunctionServerless1
cd FunctionServerless1
npm install
az login
az account set -s <subscription-id>
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name siliconserverless
```

***In command Prompt:-***

Use **`SET`**, For Bash use **`Export`**, For Powershell use **`$env:`**

I am using command prompt:-

```
SET AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=xxxxxxa7
SET AZURE_TENANT_ID=xxxxxxxx395
SET AZURE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxfae
SET AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxWrYVJc8m
```

After setting all the environment variables deploy the Function by the command below:-

```
serverless deploy
```

***Output:-***

[image]

```
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME:node
```

[image]

[image]

***Upgrade the Runtime version to 4 via Configuration settings:-***

```
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: 4
```

[image]

[image]

In order to Run the Function from Portal > Code + Test > Add the CORS settings below:-

[image]

[image]

If the issue persists, Raise a github issue [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues).

Comment: Hi Siddhesh, Thanks for your suggestion I also tried similar one. But its not good practice  to change FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 4 every time from portal.
I want a way by which we can directly change it by setting serverless.yml file or if there any other configuration is required from code side

Comment: @ganyavhad Just add   environment: 
    VARIABLE_FOO: 'foo'
     FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: '~4' In the serverless.yml The Function Extension version setting will be added along with VARIAB:E_FOO:'foo'

Comment: I tried this also but getting error as below
Error:
"Code": "Conflict",
  "Message": "Parameter with name FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION already exists."

Comment: It already exsists in your Settings as you might have added it manually, Make sure you remove it and add again with sereverless.yml??